# Sizing Transistors for 2.2hp universal motor controller

Tags: transistors, motor-controller, component-failure, universal-motor

my background is mechanical and as you can see I have just enough electrical knowledge to be dangerous.

I have an application where I'm trying to use 2xFDP51N25 in parallel
to drive a (2.2hp) universal motor from a circular saw. Bench testing no load everything works fine. The transistors short (drain to source) as soon as under load. The transistors barely get warm and do not pop at failure. The motor measures 1.3ohms and I suspect it's the start current but am out of my depth so wouldn't be surprised if it something else.  I'm looking at adding a flyback diode for the motor and new transistors with a 350A pulse rating. There's probably a good reason why you don't see this application much....lol.   I'm open to any suggestions or criticisms.     Thanks

Application:
Continuous Duty
2 x [FDPF51N25](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/FDPF51N25-195088.pdf) transistor in parallel 
with heat sinks and fan cooling
980hz PWM to gate (0-5vdc) for control
Series wound ac/dc brushed motor 1.3ohms
Tagged as 15Amps/120 volts
Supply voltage 90vdc battery

[image]

Comment: It seems you didn’t care about free wheel diode to protect the inductive kick back from the motor when switch the mosfets

Comment: Specs for Opto Gate Driver   http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/FOD3180-93816.pdf         Right now I have the output of the driver maxed out at 5 volts but think I could scale it up in the software.   What would be a safe volt/amp range for the diode 10X worse case?

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t really get what this component’s relation to my previous comment. I’m referring to FDP51N25

Comment: Sorry this was for Andy aka, below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking at adding a flyback diode for the motor

Very sensible and is likely the reason why your MOSFETs immediately died. With the inductance of the motor and up to 15 amps flowing as soon as the MOSFET turned off the energy stored in the motor's inductance would produce a massive back-emf (possibly up to thousands of volts) and smoked your MOSFETs.

So you cure that problem and then you might be faced with: -

1. Your MOSFET driver not being adequate to drive the gate capacitance of both MOSFETs wired in parallel. Please provide a link.
2. Your circuit board (or dread to think breadboard) layout may not be a healthy design that prevents other nasty things happening.
3. A 10 volt gate drive as your schematic implies is adequate for the MOSFETs but you say in your text that it is "PWM to gate (0-5vdc)" and 5 volts is far too low for these MOSFETs.
4. Your motor stall/start current could be in the realm of 60 amps and with the on-resistance being 0.03 ohms (both MOSFETs together), this would be a power dissipation of 3600 x 0.03 watts  = 108 watts and is probably OK.

Comment: Specs for Opto Gate Driver http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/FOD3180-93816.pdf  Right now I have the output of the driver maxed out at 5 volts but think I could scale it up in the software. What would be a safe volt/amp range for the diode 10X worse case?

Comment: Yeah the gate drive is denitely not enough - you should be aiming for ten volts minimum to properly turn the MOSFETs on. The diode needs to be rated at the mximum current that the motor takes but it doesn't have to be a continuous rating. Look for peak current handling capability - usually 10x greater than continuous current handling but you might need a heat sink for it.

Comment: You don't *need* to use an isolated driver - you can use a regular MOSFET driver and get better delivery of charge energy to your MOSFET gates.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I installed a diode http://ixapps.ixys.com/DataSheet/DSEP29-12A.pdf

Comment: And new transistors.  It survives now under load with a 90vdc supply to the motor.  If my arduino PWM only outputs 5volts max, could I wire a momentary switch to drop 10volts to the output of the driver when max power is needed.   In short 0-5volt PWM to throttle motor and connect  10volt (VCC from driver supply) to gate for full power.  Bad Idea?    It wouldn't be the first.

Comment: I wouldn’t entertain it. Drive your pwm with 10 volt signals or you are asking for trouble.

Comment: Wanted to add a correction.   The PWM is 0-5 volts and the gate driver output is 0-12.5 volts.  The regulator is actually supplying 12.5 volts to the gate driver. I probably should update  the schematic for clarity.

Comment: @IrishPat you probably don't need to if you have an answer you can work with. If you do update it, make sure you show it as a clear edit in case anyone coming to this question sees my answer as being contrary to your question's added detail. I would just leave it as is realistically.